# Деепричастный оборот при составном глагольном сказуемом

Tags: синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот

*Вы хотите, работая в солидной компании, купить квартиру в центре Москвы.*

К какому глаголу относится деепричастный оборот — "хотите" или "купить"? Желание купить квартиру имеет место сейчас, во время работы в солидной компании, или желание имеет место сейчас, но работа в солидной компании будет во время покупки квартиры?

Answer (score 4):

Ой-ёшеньки!

По моему глубокому убеждению (увы, не подкреплённому правилом), модальный глагол "хотеть", лексически неполноценный в данном предложении, не может рассматриваться отдельно от инфинитива.

Составное глагольное сказуемое здесь - ***хотеть купить,*** ну и, стало быть, "желание купить квартиру имеет место сейчас, во время работы в солидной компании".

Второй вариант толкования - "работа в солидной компании будет во время покупки квартиры" -  не синтаксически, а практически неуместен и диковат.

То есть деепричастный оборот относится к СГС, не дробимому на составные.

Comment: А по-моему, практически как раз очень уместен: человек мечтает, что, когда будет работать в солидной компании, купит квартиру в центре Москвы.

Comment: Галина, Ваше толкование как раз правилом подкреплено:вспомогательный глагол действительно имеет только грамматическое значение, а инфинитив - лексическое. "Хотите" обозначает желание действия, а не само действие, а вот само действие "купить" будет только тогда, когда будет работа в солидной компании. А желать он может когда и где угодно - и работая в компании, и не работая.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо! Вы развеяли мои сомнения! )))

Comment: Василий, "но работа в солидной компании будет во время покупки квартиры" - ето как же-с? О_о Ето квартира будет следствием работы на тёпленьком местечке, не наоборот.

Comment: @Людмила , А если так: "Работая в солидной компании, вы хотите купить квартиру в центре Москвы."? Здесь он желает не  когда и где угодно, а именно работая. Не так ли?

Comment: Конечно, но желает-то он именно купить квартиру, а не отвлечённо "желает", следовательно дееприч. оборот относится не к вспомогательному глаголу "желает", а к инфинитиву, который обозначает действие "купить".

Comment: Вспомогательный - он и есть вспомогательный, самостоятельного значения действия сказуемого у него нет, а оборот относится к сказуемому. Распространить можно и так: Он желал бы, если б вообще способен был чего-то желать, купить квартиру... И даже тогда это было бы СГС и придаточное относилось бы ко всему сказуемому, а не к вспомогательному глаголу. Разделять СГС нельзя, а чисто формально кажется, что придаточное поясняет глагол желает.