# Деепричастный оборот и придаточное времени при СГС

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, деепричастный-оборот, инфинитив

> 1.1. *Полностью освоив текущее направление, мы планируем развивать новое.*

Смысл «мы уже освоили и сейчас планируем» или «мы планируем развивать тогда, когда освоим»?

Если поставить оборот перед инфинитивом, вроде бы можно добиться однозначного второго смысла:

> 1.2. *Мы планируем, полностью освоив текущее направление, развивать новое.*

За счёт такой позиции деепричастный оборот по смыслу больше примыкает к инфинитиву, и то, что развитие нового направления будет производиться только после освоения текущего, уже становится как бы частью объекта планирования.

Если переставить оборот в конец предложения, то также возможны оба смысла:

> 1.3. *Мы планируем развивать новое направление, полностью освоив текущее.*

——————————————————

Аналогичный пример с деепричастием несовершенного вида:

> 2.1. *Работая в солидной компании, я хочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы.*

Та же самая неоднозначность: «работая, хочу» или «хочу купить тогда, когда буду работать»?

> 2.2. *Я хочу, работая в солидной компании, купить квартиру в центре Москвы.*

Во этом варианте также усиливается связь деепричастного оборота с инфинитивом, и то, что покупка квартиры будет производиться только во время работы в солидной компании, становится частью объекта желания.

Однако если сменить лицо глагола с первого на второе, то почему‑то опять можно понять двояко:

> 2.3. *Вы хотите, работая в солидной компании, купить квартиру в центре Москвы.*

То ли «вы уже работаете и хотите купить», то ли «вы хотите купить, но только тогда, когда будете работать».

Последний же вариант в данном случае несуразен:

> 2.4. *Я хочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, работая в солидной компании.*

После того как высказана основная мысль — «я хочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы», указание на приуроченность к времени работы в солидной компании кажется лишним.

**Хотелось бы получить точный ответ — какие факторы (позиция деепричастного оборота, его вид, время вспомогательного глагола в составном глагольном сказуемом) определяют, относится ли деепричастный оборот ко всему СГС или только к инфинитиву.**

Пока я понял только одно: позиция деепричастного оборота в предложении с СГС явно влияет на его семантику.

Хорошим решением для ликвидации двусмысленности становится замена деепричастного оборота на придаточное времени:

> 3.1. *Мы планируем развивать новое направление, когда полностью освоим текущее.*

Разное время вспомогательного глагола в главном и глагола в придаточном не даёт их соотнести.

Однако в учебниках написано, что придаточные времени относятся ко всему главному предложению, а здесь придаточное относится лишь к части СГС — инфинитиву. **В учебниках неточность?**

К слову, двусмысленность снова возникает, если поставить вспомогательный глагол в будущее время:

> 3.2. *Совет директоров наверняка запланирует развивать новое направление, когда текущее будет полностью освоено.*

«Запланирует тогда, когда текущее направление будет полностью освоено» или «запланирует в некоторый момент в будущем, но развивать будут тогда, когда текущее направление будет полностью освоено»?

**Как поступать в таком случае?**

———————————

**Похожие вопросы**:

[Деепричастный оборот при составном глагольном сказуемом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/446970/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)‑сказуемом

[Позиция обстоятельства при СГС (переформулирован)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454771/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%A1%D0%93%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD/455796#455796)

Comment: Это всё, конечно, интересно. Но такое использование оборотов и времён некорректно само по себе - а именно замена будущего времени на настоящее. Это же не английский, где подобное существует. *Хочу купить тогда* - неверно, ***захочу** купить тогда* - верно. Использование деепричастия настоящего времени вместо придаточного будущего времени тоже некорректно. Ведь нет деепричастий именно будущего времени. Или вы просто проводите эксперименты над смыслом вне корректности использования времён?

Comment: @oleedd Деепричастия настоящего времени, насколько я знаю, выражают действие, которое происходит одновременно с действием, выраженным опорным глаголом, а тот может быть любого времени.

Answer (score 3):

Я не отвечаю Вам конкретно (и уж тем более не даю точный ответ), но хочу поделиться своим **впечатлением от Ваших вопросов**. Я надеюсь, что эта информация может оказаться  для Вас полезной. Если что-то Вам не понравится в моем ответе, то я заранее прошу извинить меня, так как всё говорится с самыми добрыми чувствами и намерениями.

Когда я читаю Ваши вопросы, то мне кажется, что я общаюсь **с искусственным интеллектом (в положительном смысле).** В чем-то такой интеллект превосходит человеческий разум, но при этом он может испытывать трудности при понимании вполне обычных вещей, в частности это касается языка.

1) **Вы обращаетесь с синтаксисом, как с механическим конструктором**, считая, что можно комбинировать структурные элементы в любом порядке, но это не так.  В настоящее время изучение грамматики подводит нас к такому пониманию речи, когда  грамматическая форма и семантика изучаются совместно  (так называемое семантическое согласование).

Что это означает?   К примеру, согласно структурным схемам, деепричастный оборот может занимать любую позицию (в начале, в конце и в середине предложения). Но каждый вариант должен быть соотнесен с коммуникативной ситуацией.

Вот как это может выглядеть в вашем случае (например, в виде ответов на вопросы).

– Каковы ваши планы на будущее?  – Наша компания не стоит на месте. Полностью освоив текущее направление, мы планируем развивать новое.

– Это направление в технике возникло недавно, вы планирует его развитие? – Пока у нас нет таких возможностей. Заниматься чем-то новым мы сможем, полностью освоив текущее направление (если/когда освоим…).

2) **Рассмотрим теперь временной  аспект этой темы.** Если ***планировать*** – модальный глагол (связка в СГС), то в словаре он помечен следующим образом: 4. Разг. Иметь намерение сделать что-л.

Глагол ***планировать*** относится к настоящему моменту речи, а соотнесенность во времени рассматривается между действиями, выраженными  инфинитивом СГС и деепричастием, поэтому модальный глагол в этих временных рамках вообще, как мне кажется, не участвует.

**Но и  тут при определении времени действия  всё не так просто.** Если почитать грамматику Розенталя, то можно кое-что  узнать на эту тему.  Что именно? Классическое правило об одновременности действий для деепричастия несовершенного вида и смещения по времени для деепричастия совершенного вида всем известно. Но вот что интересно:  правило соотношения времен перестает действовать, **если оборот  приравнивается к обстоятельственному придаточному,** например, называет условие действия (если закончим текущее направление).

3)   **И позиция деепричастного оборота**  (в частности, совершенного вида) очень важна: **в препозиции** оборот обычно выражает **предшествующее действие**, а последующее  или одновременное действие встречается значительно реже, при этом оборот находится в постпозиции. Если рассматривать придаточные предложения, там также позиция очень важна и влияет на семантику (это особая тема).

4) Таким образом, **множество этих нюансов всегда учитывается при общении**, определяет нужный смысл и избавляет говорящих от угадывания возможных вариантов.  Двусмысленность воспринимается как недостаток в построении текста. Кроме того, ситуация обычно тоже подсказывает, что имеет в виду ваш собеседник.

5) Учитывая всё это, можно понять, почему Ваши вопросы обычными пользователями **не воспринимаются как актуальные** – для них таких проблем просто не существуют, если человек знаком с  основными грамматическими правилами.  Причем часто всё это происходит на интуитивном уровне, то есть очень важен  практический навык грамотной речи. Но если нужно совершенствовать свои знания, **то лучше начинать не с «логических игр», а с подробного изучения грамматики.**

Answer (score 1):

> Пока я понял только одно: позиция деепричастного оборота в предложении с СГС явно влияет на его семантику.

По-моему, Вы это надумываете. Где бы ни стоял деепричастный оборот, смысл только один, а именно: ***в будущем освоим и, освоив, планируем развивать.***

> Хорошим решением для ликвидации двусмысленности становится замена деепричастного оборота на придаточное времени.
>
> *3.1. Мы планируем развивать новое направление, когда полностью освоим текущее.*

Да, можно так, можно и с ДО (1.1, 1.2 или 1.3 на выбор), а если в другом смысле, тогда:

> Мы полностью освоили текущее направление и планируем развивать новое.

Во вторых предложениях, как я уже сказал, смысл *уже работаю и планирую в будущем* отсекается, остаётся один (когда буду работать, хочу), но и его, на мой взгляд, гораздо правильнее выразить, как в скобках, а не с помощью ДО, как у Вас.

Могу ошибаться, но мне это так видится.

Предложение 3.2, согласен, можно понять двусмысленно. Но вот в этом предложении как раз перестановка может поменять смысл, как мне кажется. Если на первое место поставить придаточное с "когда", то смысл будет (опять же IMHO) *только когда будет освоено, запланирует.*

Ещё раз задумавшись, понял, что мне кажется в принципе странным употреблять ДО в контексте будущего. И [вот](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/786-36_predlozheniya_s_deeprichastnymi_oborotami.html) что я нашёл по этому поводу:

*Не рекомендуется употребление деепричастий в предложениях, где глагол-сказуемое стоит в форме будущего времени.*

*Ср.: **Приехав** в город своего детства, я обязательно **встречусь** со школьными друзьями и моей первой учительницей.*

Мне кажется, это **ключевой** момент.

Comment: *Где бы ни стоял причастный (вы, видимо, имели в виду деепричастный) оборот, смысл только один, а именно: в будущем освоим и, освоив, планируем развивать*. Но глагол «планируем» же настоящего времени. Тогда нужно «будем планировать». То же самое с «когда буду работать, хочу» — для вашего варианта необходимо «буду хотеть».

Comment: Спасибо за правки, Василий! Правильно, планируем сейчас развивать потом; хочу сейчас купить потом, как смогу. А вообще, ДО в контексте будущего очень странно звучит. Нашёл этому подтверждение, сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь наблюдаем замену придаточного времени на деепричастный оборот:
*Я захочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, если буду работать в солидной компании.*
Будущее время необходимо сохранить — иначе нарушение грамматики:
*Я захочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, работая в солидной компании.*

Но такая замена очень плохо звучит и не рекомендуется.

В английском можно наблюдать использование настоящего времени вместо будущего — но в придаточном:
*I will help when I can.* || Я помогу, когда могу. В русском необходимо "смогу".

Но парадокс в том, что в русском это иногда возможно в основной части — при указании на время:
*Завтра мы идём на пикник.

Я работаю в офисе завтра.*
Но при придаточном необходимо будущее время:
*Мы пойдём на пикник, когда появится свободное время.*

*Мы планируем развивАть новое направление, полностью освоив текущее направление.*
Планируем уже сейчас — иначе было бы "запланируем" или "будем планировать". А развивать — полностью освоив текущее.

> В учебниках неточность?

**3.1.** Придаточное времени действительно относится ко всему главному предложению. Это довольно очевидный факт. Но ведь вопрос к придаточному ставим именно от глагола (*развивать когда именно?*). То есть смысловой переход осуществляется за счёт глагола.

**3.2.** А вот тут действительно есть два варианта. Но они в языке не бывают абсолютно равносильными. Всегда что-то рациональнее. Логическое ударение естественно падает на "запланирует" (этому способствует слово "наверняка"), другой вариант хуже читается — но кто-то может понять именно так.

> Как поступать в таком случае?

1) Заменить один глагол на существительное:
*Совет директоров наверняка запланирует развитие нового направления, когда текущее будет полностью освоено.* || Звучит более официально.
2) Переставить нужное слово в начальные позиции, чтобы на него или на соседнее слово упало логическое ударение (два варианта):
*РазвИвать нОвое направление совет директоров наверняка запланирует, когда текущее будет полностью освоено.*
3) Добавить наречие перед нужным словом, чтобы ударение упало на него:
*Совет директоров наверняка запланирует эффективно развивАть новое направление, когда текущее будет полностью освоено.*