# Хочу быть космонавтом когда стану взрослым

Tags: времена

Вот [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456777) oleedd писал

> Но такое использование оборотов и времён некорректно само по себе - а именно замена будущего времени на настоящее. Это же не английский, где подобное существует. Хочу купить тогда - неверно, захочу купить тогда - верно.

Но простите, неужели в такой фразе есть ошибка:

*"Хочу быть космонавтом когда стану взрослым"*?

Ошибается ли oleedd или он прав и надо писать

*"Захочу быть космонавтом когда стану взрослым"*?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере ошибки нет:
*Хочу [уже сейчас] быть космонавтом, когда стану взрослым.* || Придаточное относится к инфинитиву:
*Быть тогда, когда стану взрослым.*

В том вопросе прокомментировал сразу и упустил то, что там был инфинитив. А имелось в виду использование "хочу тогда" вместо "захочу тогда".

Comment: Хорошо. Разберем ваш дальнейший ход мысли. Согласны ли вы с тем что ваши претензии к настоящему времени в строках
"Здесь наблюдаем замену придаточного времени на деепричастный оборот:
Я захочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, если буду работать в солидной компании.
Будущее время необходимо сохранить — иначе нарушение грамматики:
Я захочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, работая в солидной компании." не обоснованы?

Comment: и правомерно писать:
"Я хочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, когда буду работать в солидной компании.
Я хочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, работая в солидной компании."

Comment: Получается, что да. Тогда сам запутался. Вот и хорошо, что вы поправили. Но такое предложение плохо звучит. *Купить, когда будет работать* - никакой логики.

Comment: Да, логики маловато. Если кто-то спрашивает "Когда вы хотите купить квартиру?". "Я хочу купить квартиру в центре Москвы, когда буду работать в солидной компании."

Comment: Тот вопрос некорректно объяснён. Я долго не мог понять, что вообще спрашивается. Вот тут: *Смысл «мы уже освоили и сейчас планируем» или «мы планируем развивать тогда, когда освоим»?* "мы планируем" нужно было вообще убрать, тогда понятно, что второй вариант - это отношение к инфинитиву. Вот теперь, полностью понимая вопрос, у меня есть ответ. Но теперь очень неудобно отвечать, раз претензии были необоснованными. А сам автор не уточнил те моменты, которые я не так понял.

Comment: Да, по-моему там сам автор все и объяснил в своем вопросе. Он говорил что деепричастие относится то к основному глаголу, то к инфинитиву. В зависимости от всяких мелочей типа контекста или порядка оборотов. Получаются двусмысленные фразы, но это не критично ибо контекст всегда вносит точность.

Comment: Там нет ни одной _двусмысленной_ фразы (там где "запланируют" - не в счёт, она без деепричастий) - есть "корявые", но и из них смысл вывести можно лишь один, даже если он не всегда "авторский".

Comment: @Alex_ander Почему нет двусмысленных фраз? *Хочу, уже работая в солидной компании. Купить, когда-то работая в солидной компании.* Вот и я сразу не понял.

Comment: _Я хочу, работая в солидной компании, купить квартиру в центре Москвы._ Здесь нет оснований для уже/ещё (_временной_ контекст отсутствует полностью), а всё содержание привязано к **хочу**. Хочу, разумеется, того, чего нет,  т. е. в данный момент имею желание купить. Хочу купить при каких сопутствующих обстоятельствах? Работая в солидной компании. Ничего другого при таком **порядке слов** быть не может, в отличие от первого варианта предложения, начинающегося с "Работая".  Без деепричастий: _Я хочу работать в солидной компании и (в какой-то момент) купить квартиру в центре Москвы._

Comment: @Alex_ander Да может быть другое, просто что-то хуже воспринимается. *Я хочу, раз работаю в солидной компании, купить квартиру в центре Москвы.*

Comment: Но тогда и говорить надо яснее (напр. добавить это самое "раз"), а если человек по неразборчивости своей переставил слова, то это его ошибка: его обязательно поймут иначе, чем он ожидал - смысл _однозначно другой_.

Answer (score 1):

*Неужели в такой фразе есть ошибка: "Хочу быть космонавтом когда стану взрослым"?*

Фраза о желании быть космонавтом ко времени своего взросления определённо требует коррекции: «Хочу стать космонавтом (*тогда*), когда буду взрослым». Только в такой последовательности могут следовать события — взросление человека, а затем и становление его как личности и профессионала. И потому лишь в контексте детскости изложения фраза может быть проходной.

---

*Ошибается ли oleedd или он прав и надо писать: "Захочу быть космонавтом когда стану взрослым"?*

Если говорить только о слове *захочу*, то оно оправдывается представлением о желаниях как легко управляемых, а стало быть, и планируемых.

> А вот как, сказал я ему: я ― свободен, совсем, передвигаюсь куда хочу,
> когда хочу и как хочу… [Дина Рубина. Двойная фамилия (1986)]
> "Ни один листок не колыхнётся в Чили, если я этого не захочу. [Олег Поляковский. Неподсуден // «Вокруг света», 2003.09.15]